# Convert json data to dictionary

Tags: python

I am trying to convert my json data into a dictionary with key the id of the json data. for example lets say i have the following json:

```
{
"id": "1",
"name": "John",
"surname": "Smith"
},
{
"id": "2",
"name": "Steve",
"surname": "Ger"
}
```

And i want to construct a new dictionary which includes the id as a key and save it into a file so i wrote the following code:

```
json_dict = []
request = requests.get('http://example.com/...')
with open("data.json", "w") as out:
            loaded_data = json.loads(request.text)
            for list_item in loaded_data:
                json_dict.append({"id": list_item["id"], "data": list_item })
            out.write(json.dumps(json_dict))
```

In the file i get the following output:

```
[{"data": {"id":"1",
           "name":"John",
           "Surname":"Smith"
           }
    },
    {"data": {"id":"2",
           "name":"Steve",
           "Surname":"Ger"
           }
    },
]
```

Why the id is not included in my dict before data ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with json, it's just plain Python dicts and lists (the fact that  the source comes from deserialized json and the result is serializedback to json is totally irellevant here).

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you're looking at a ghost here.  You probably tested wrong.  It will go away when you try to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example for us (i. e. with a fixed string as input instead of a `request` call, with a `print` instead of an `out.write`, etc).

This is my test in which I could not reproduce the problem:

```
entries = [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "John",
    "surname": "Smith"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Steve",
    "surname": "Ger"
  }
]

json_dict = []
for i in entries:
  json_dict.append({"id":i["id"], "data": i})
json.dumps(json_dict, indent=2)
```

This prints as expected:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "data": {
      "id": "1",
      "surname": "Smith",
      "name": "John"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "data": {
      "id": "2",
      "surname": "Ger",
      "name": "Steve"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this instead:

```
json_dict = []
with open('data.json', 'w) as f:
    loaded_data = json.loads(request.text)
        for list_item in loaded_data:
            json_dict.append({list_item['id'] : list_item})
```

Comment: Hehe..small mistake there..I corrected the error,had put a list as a key..check answer now and if it helps plz mark as read to close it